# Placing items above table view in a table view controller that do not scroll Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, user-interface, uinavigationcontroller

This issue is something I have been struggling with for a while and have been able to get around for the most part by using was seem like hacky techniques but I am needing a better way to accomplish this now.

My question is how do you add UI elements above a table view (in a table view controller) and make them stick to the view (the should not scroll with the table view). For example adding a navigation bar is simple because you can just embed in a navigation controller to the table controller. But what if you want to add say a tab bar below the navigation bar but above the table view? So that the table view scrolls and the tab bar sticks to the bottom of the navigation bar and does not scroll with it.

Ive tried to do this by placing it in the storyboard just below the navigation bar and just above the tableview but it just scrolls with the table.

Any help on this is very much appreciated!

Comment: If you want custom content between a tableView and the nav bar, you could just use a regular `UIViewController` and just add whatever content below the nav bar you want, then add a `UITableView` below that

Comment: Thats how I am doing it now, I just feel like there should be a way to do it directly using a table view controller.

Comment: I agree with @Pierce.  I will almost never use a UITableViewController.  They are too limited and offer little benefit over a UIViewController containing a UITableView

Comment: Interestering, thats how I feel as well. For some reason I just figured there was a better way. Thank you both for your comments!

Comment: As somewhat of a followup question. When using a table view controller you have direct access to methods such as hiding the nav bar on swipe. Is there a simple way to do this when a table view is a subview of a UIViewController?